# События подключения и отключения в UDP

Tags: клиент-сервер, udp

В `TCP`-соединении сервер может отследить момент подключения и момент отключения клиента. Как это реализовано в `UDP`, где нет непосредственно подключения к серверу (оно производится каждый раз перед отправкой пакета)?

Например, есть игра, в которой при подключении пользователю выдается определенный слот (место в игре), а при потере клиентом соединения сервер должен освободить его слот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На уровне OS (и протокола) в UDP вообще отсутствует "подключение" (такого понятия нет). Каждый пакет отправляется (и получается из сети) независимо от остальных.

Поэтому вся симуляция "подключений" перекладывается на прикладную программу, которая должна проводить это в соответствии со своей логикой.

Answer (score 1):

Это реализуется т.н."сердцебиением" (heartbeat), то есть сервер должен регулярно получать пакет от клиента. Если за истёкшее время ожидания пакета нет, то сервер считает, что клиент отключился. Этот процесс чем-то напоминает пингование. Реализуется, как уже указали, на прикладном уровне.